# Xamarin Android Player installation error 2203

Tags: xamarin, virtualbox, xamarin-android-player

When I try to install Xamarin Android Player version 0.6.5.0

```
Error: 2203
```

The error starts when android player asks to install Virtual Box(which comes attached to the setup). First error is shown in Virtual Box installation and then in Xamarin Android Player installation.

I gave full access to temp folders which did not help.

Comment: Which version of VirtualBox do you have installed? Also what operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1 Pro and its virtual box something...4.3.1 I don't know what is the version exactly but its greater than 4.0.0

Comment: Have you tried downloading the latest version of VirtualBox directly? https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: well I have solved the problem by reinstalling the whole windows all over again and then install virtual box and android player but then I deleted them cause its was total garbage. As soon as I installed the program it messed up my network setting and uninstalled the Ethernet IPv4 protocol

Comment: It sounds like you encountered a problem with VirtualBox. Did it removed your IPv4 protocol during installation? Or when you tried to run Xamarin Android Player?

Comment: yeah, now I think that too.  I have a problem with virtual box cause I had some problems before too.

Comment: Were you able to use Xamarin Android Player at all before you removed it?

Comment: nah cause virtual box setup or something comes with android player setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Error 2203` is the windows error when you cannot access the default temporary folder in Windows (%temp%). A third-party program may restrict access to this folder, or there may not be sufficient permissions assigned to it.

Workaround:

1. Open a command prompt with administrator permissions (cmd.exe)
2. Create a new directory: Example: `md c:\temp`
3. Set the temp folder location to the new temp folder `set temp=c:\temp`
4. Start the Xamarin Android Player Installation

Download latest version: https://xamarin.com/android-player